# Dapper problem with a nullable Guid? types

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have problem with Dapper and `Guid?` type. I created that demo project:

Database MySQL (table `entities`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `entities` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `notnullguid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `nullguid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

First `Guid` field - not null, second - nullable (with `NULL` as default value).

Demo data:

| id | notnullguid | nullguid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7b137c4e-38db-11eb-adec-a85e45e499a0 | NULL |
| 2 | f57b9036-38db-11eb-adec-a85e45e499a0 | f57b906b-38db-11eb-adec-a85e45e499a0 |

My entity:

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public Guid NotNullGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid? NullGuid { get; set; }
}
```

My query:

```cs
//PROBLEM:
Entity e1 = db.Query<Entity>("SELECT * FROM entities WHERE id=1").First(); //Not working

//WORKING - all variations:
Entity e2 = db.Query<Entity>("SELECT * FROM entities WHERE id=2").First(); //Working
Entity e3 = db.Query<Entity>("SELECT notnullguid FROM ents WHERE id=1;").First(); //Working
Entity e4 = db.Query<Entity>("SELECT notnullguid, NULL as nullguid FROM ents WHERE id=1;").First(); //Working
Entity e5 = db.Query<Entity>("SELECT notnullguid, IFNULL(nullguid, NULL) FROM ents WHERE id=1;").First(); //Working
```

If I get `id=1` I have that exception:

[image: Screen shot]

> System.Data.DataException: 'Error parsing column 2
> (nullguid=7b137c4e-38db-11eb-adec-a85e45e499a0 - Object)'   This
> exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Data.DataException   HResult=0x80131501   Message=Error parsing
> column 2 (nullguid=7b137c4e-38db-11eb-adec-a85e45e499a0 - Object)
> Source=Dapper   StackTrace:    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index,
> IDataReader reader, Object value) in /*/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3665
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__140`1.MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1102    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param,
> IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /*/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line
> 725    at DapperGuidParsing.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\Dmytro\source\repos\DapperGuidParsing\DapperGuidParsing\Program.cs:line
> 21
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(System.ExceptionArgument,
> System.ExceptionResource)
> System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(byte[], int, int)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(int, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField, MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.this[int].get(int)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(int, bool)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValue(int)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.this[int].get(int) Inner Exception 1: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number
> required.

Why? :| And how I can fix this?

Some tech info: `.NET Core 3.1 Console App`, `Dapper 2.0.78`, `MySql.Data 8.0.22`.

Comment: What if you do `Select notnullguid, nullguid From entities Where id =1`?

Comment: @juharr same exception like with just `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `entities`.

Comment: @mjwills MySQL and script added in main post

Comment: Post the *full* exception, not just the message. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Click Details` on the exception popup. The full text contains the stack trace that shows which chain of calls resulted in the exception. The problem could be caused by a specific Dapper method, or by the MySQL driver itself. Oracle's drivers leave something to be desired, which is why people created third-party providers [like MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated.

Comment: That's still not the *full* exception, only part of the stack trace. The Dapper calls are missing. This looks like a Connector/.NET bug. The error occurs in `MySqlDataReader.GetValue(int)` and has nothing to do with Dapper - there's no attempt to read a specific type, just the value as a "raw" object. It's thrown when attempting to convert the binary response to a string. Even though there's no string involved.  Have you tried this with [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/)?

Comment: You can determine if this is a provider bug by using a `MySqlCommand` and `ExecuteReader` to run the query, then try to read the field with `GetValue()`. I suspect the same problem will occur

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thx for your support and sorry for my english. I tried with MySqlConnector and got another exception (you can see in main post). It's strange behavior :\

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry, that exception about my connection string. And I removed 'Allow Batch' - all code is worked. Now, I write answer. Big Thx!

Comment: wow, i ran into the exact problem, too. I tried to workarround with a custom converter, but even with a custom converter, it will not work (`SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid?>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything worked as it should, when you install Nuget package [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/)

```
//Working
IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);

//Not working (default MySqlConnection from MySql.Data package)
//IDbConnection db = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I confirm that this works. You safed my day! :-) As it seems, `MySqlConnector` is a 1:1 replacement for `MySql.Data`, except for namespace name.

Comment: It's unbelievable.